# How are these two graphs related (if they even are)?

Tags: graph-theory

I was trying to understand factoring numbers from a different perspective. Through a long convoluted route, I came up with a directed graph where if you can find the edges pointing to a given vertex you can factor the number at that vertex. This came from looking at the sequences of multiples of two numbers with a given mean, and trying to turn those sequences into a directed graph (each number points to every other number which follows it in some such sequence) - if you have one number in this sequence, the previous number in the sequence will tell you which sequence you're looking at, which corresponds to the mean of some two multiples, which is enough information to figure out those two multiples without needing to factor the number.

That graph is defined with the natural numbers as vertices, and edges directed from every $x \rightarrow cx - c^{2} + c$ for every natural number $c$ (where the right hand side is still restricted to the natural numbers). Let's call this graph A.

Another graph which has this property (the property that knowing the edges pointing to a given vertex allows you to factor the number at that vertex) is the graph where natural numbers point to their multiples: so exactly the same as the above, except using $x \rightarrow cx$ instead of $x \rightarrow cx - c^{2} + c$. Let's call this graph B.

So clearly in graph B, to go backwards from any $cx$ to an $x$ is equivalent to finding some $c$ (equivalent to factoring).

And also, in graph A, to go backwards from any $cx - c ^ {2} + c$, you also need to find some factor $c$ (since that expression factors into $c(x - c + 1)$, giving us factors $c$ and $(x - c + 1)$).

But on some level, I'm still confused, because both of these graphs look quite different when you draw them out/visualize them.

I would guess these graphs are somehow related, but I'm struggling to see how. Perhaps there is some transformation which takes one graph to the other and maintains the structure? Or perhaps we can filter out some obviously unnecessary edges from graph B (since A seems more hand-wavily "sparse") and then we can come up with some correspondence between them?

I might also just be confusing myself a lot here and there might be a much simpler explanation for what these two graphs are doing which I would also appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

The graphs are related but in a perhaps confusing way.

For each number $c$ the connection is straightforward. Suppose that Graph A has an edge :$$u\rightarrow v$$
This corresponds exactly with the edge in Graph B: $$u+c\rightarrow v+c$$

*Simple proof*

In A, $v=uc$.

In B, $u+c$ maps to $c((u+c)-c+1)=uc+c.$

So for a fixed $c$ the graphs are isomorphic.

However, these graphs are actually drawn for lots of different values of $c$. Therefore there are different sets of edges in A, each corresponding in a different way to a set of edges in B.